# Python overwrite traceback call in objects

Tags: python

I have a deeply nested object of the same class, I want to detect the traceback attribute error, so I can print("there is no attribute in this level") message rather than displaying a traceback attribute error message.

Comment: use try-except then print the message in except.

Comment: Have you considered using `.get()` to retrieve the attribute?

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks, it is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: By the way, welcome back.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `try-except` clause here:

```
try:
    #Your code here (Whatever thing gets to an attribute error)
except AttributeError:
    print("there is no attribute in this level")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **getattr** magic method.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
           print("there is no attribute in this level")
```

Comment: This will print to the console and return `None` when you access a missing attribute. I highly doubt this is what you want...

Comment: The whole purpose of the try except loop, as in any language with a try method, is to access the error before it prints to the console. changing the message is almost guaranteed to be the most common use case, barring maybe writing to a `logfile` or tying `stderr` to `stdout`. It is generally considered good practice when you need to hide your implementation from the end user. If your users can see system error messages, they may or may not recognize the commands or functions that caused them.